# Binding List of Lists in MVC 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, nested-lists

I need to handle a `List<List<T>>` in a form and couldn't find how to proceed with old version of MVC and .NET.

I did try the following:

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<List<Item>> ListA { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Spec { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
    public string Field4 { get; set; }
    public string Field5 { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyModel>" %>

<% for(int i = 0; i < Model.ListA.Count; i++) { %>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <input disabled="disabled" value="Name" />
            <input disabled="disabled" value="Spec" />
            <input disabled="disabled" value="Type" />
            <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 1" />
            <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 2" />
            <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 3" />
            <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 4" />
            <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 5" />
        </div>
        <% for(int j = 0; j < Model.ListA[i].Count; j++) { %>
            <div>
                <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListA[i][j].Name)%>
                <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListA[i][j].Spec)%>
                <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListA[i][j].Type)%>
                <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListA[i][j].Field1)%>
                <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListA[i][j].Field2)%>
                <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListA[i][j].Field3)%>
                <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListA[i][j].Field4)%>
                <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListA[i][j].Field5)%>
            </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyAction(int Id)
{
    // MyModel modObj = MyService.GetModelById(Id);
    MyModel modObj = new MyModel
    {
        ListA = new List<List<Item>>
        {
            new List<Item>
            {
                new Item { Name = "0 - 0" },
                new Item { Name = "0 - 1" },
                new Item { Name = "0 - 2" }
            },
            new List<Item>
            {
                new Item { Name = "1 - 0" },
                new Item { Name = "1 - 1" },
                new Item { Name = "1 - 2" }
            }
        }
    }

    return View(modObj);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    // anything
    return null;
}
```

**My problem is that currently, even if I can correctly see the editors for every item** (here the two lists of three items), **when I post it back, I only see the first list of three items in the controller.**

I also tried to change my model to:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public List<ItemList> ListA { get; set; }
}

public class ItemList
{
    public string PropId { get; set; }
    public List<Item> ListB { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Spec { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
    public string Field4 { get; set; }
    public string Field5 { get; set; }
}
```

and changed my View and Controller accordingly, but I still get the same result: **the first List level only contains one List when I post it back** - I only get `"0 - 0"`, `"0 - 1"` & `"0 - 2"` when setting a breakpoint in the POST method of the controller.

I'm out of idea here.

**Edit:** To answer Jonny's question, this is how it looks like with `List<ItemList>`:

```html
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Name" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Spec" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Type" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 1" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 2" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 3" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 4" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 5" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[0].Name" id="ListA_0__ListB_0__Name" type="text" value="0 - 0"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[0].Spec" id="ListA_0__ListB_0__Spec" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[0].Type" id="ListA_0__ListB_0__Type" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[0].Field1" id="ListA_0__ListB_0__Field1" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[0].Field2" id="ListA_0__ListB_0__Field2" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[0].Field3" id="ListA_0__ListB_0__Field3" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[0].Field4" id="ListA_0__ListB_0__Field4" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[0].Field5" id="ListA_0__ListB_0__Field5" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[1].Name" id="ListA_0__ListB_1__Name" type="text" value="0 - 1"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[1].Spec" id="ListA_0__ListB_1__Spec" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[1].Type" id="ListA_0__ListB_1__Type" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[1].Field1" id="ListA_0__ListB_1__Field1" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[1].Field2" id="ListA_0__ListB_1__Field2" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[1].Field3" id="ListA_0__ListB_1__Field3" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[1].Field4" id="ListA_0__ListB_1__Field4" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[1].Field5" id="ListA_0__ListB_1__Field5" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[2].Name" id="ListA_0__ListB_2__Name" type="text" value="0 - 2"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[2].Spec" id="ListA_0__ListB_2__Spec" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[2].Type" id="ListA_0__ListB_2__Type" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[2].Field1" id="ListA_0__ListB_2__Field1" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[2].Field2" id="ListA_0__ListB_2__Field2" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[2].Field3" id="ListA_0__ListB_2__Field3" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[2].Field4" id="ListA_0__ListB_2__Field4" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0].ListB[2].Field5" id="ListA_0__ListB_2__Field5" type="text"></input>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Name" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Spec" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Type" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 1" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 2" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 3" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 4" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 5" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[0].Name" id="ListA_1__ListB_0__Name" type="text" value="1 - 0"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[0].Spec" id="ListA_1__ListB_0__Spec" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[0].Type" id="ListA_1__ListB_0__Type" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[0].Field1" id="ListA_1__ListB_0__Field1" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[0].Field2" id="ListA_1__ListB_0__Field2" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[0].Field3" id="ListA_1__ListB_0__Field3" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[0].Field4" id="ListA_1__ListB_0__Field4" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[0].Field5" id="ListA_1__ListB_0__Field5" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[1].Name" id="ListA_1__ListB_1__Name" type="text" value="1 - 1"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[1].Spec" id="ListA_1__ListB_1__Spec" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[1].Type" id="ListA_1__ListB_1__Type" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[1].Field1" id="ListA_1__ListB_1__Field1" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[1].Field2" id="ListA_1__ListB_1__Field2" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[1].Field3" id="ListA_1__ListB_1__Field3" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[1].Field4" id="ListA_1__ListB_1__Field4" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[1].Field5" id="ListA_1__ListB_1__Field5" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[2].Name" id="ListA_1__ListB_2__Name" type="text" value="1 - 2"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[2].Spec" id="ListA_1__ListB_2__Spec" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[2].Type" id="ListA_1__ListB_2__Type" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[2].Field1" id="ListA_1__ListB_2__Field1" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[2].Field2" id="ListA_1__ListB_2__Field2" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[2].Field3" id="ListA_1__ListB_2__Field3" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[2].Field4" id="ListA_1__ListB_2__Field4" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1].ListB[2].Field5" id="ListA_1__ListB_2__Field5" type="text"></input>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

and with `List<List<Item>>`:

```html
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Name" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Spec" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Type" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 1" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 2" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 3" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 4" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 5" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="ListA[0][0].Name" id="ListA_0__0__Name" type="text" value="0 - 0"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][0].Spec" id="ListA_0__0__Spec" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][0].Type" id="ListA_0__0__Type" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][0].Field1" id="ListA_0__0__Field1" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][0].Field2" id="ListA_0__0__Field2" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][0].Field3" id="ListA_0__0__Field3" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][0].Field4" id="ListA_0__0__Field4" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][0].Field5" id="ListA_0__0__Field5" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="ListA[0][1].Name" id="ListA_0__1__Name" type="text" value="0 - 1"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][1].Spec" id="ListA_0__1__Spec" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][1].Type" id="ListA_0__1__Type" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][1].Field1" id="ListA_0__1__Field1" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][1].Field2" id="ListA_0__1__Field2" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][1].Field3" id="ListA_0__1__Field3" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][1].Field4" id="ListA_0__1__Field4" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][1].Field5" id="ListA_0__1__Field5" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="ListA[0][2].Name" id="ListA_0__2__Name" type="text" value="0 - 2"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][2].Spec" id="ListA_0__2__Spec" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][2].Type" id="ListA_0__2__Type" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][2].Field1" id="ListA_0__2__Field1" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][2].Field2" id="ListA_0__2__Field2" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][2].Field3" id="ListA_0__2__Field3" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][2].Field4" id="ListA_0__2__Field4" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[0][2].Field5" id="ListA_0__2__Field5" type="text"></input>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Name" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Spec" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Type" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 1" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 2" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 3" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 4" />
        <input disabled="disabled" value="Field 5" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="ListA[1][0].Name" id="ListA_1__0__Name" type="text" value="1 - 0"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][0].Spec" id="ListA_1__0__Spec" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][0].Type" id="ListA_1__0__Type" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][0].Field1" id="ListA_1__0__Field1" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][0].Field2" id="ListA_1__0__Field2" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][0].Field3" id="ListA_1__0__Field3" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][0].Field4" id="ListA_1__0__Field4" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][0].Field5" id="ListA_1__0__Field5" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="ListA[1][1].Name" id="ListA_1__1__Name" type="text" value="1 - 1"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][1].Spec" id="ListA_1__1__Spec" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][1].Type" id="ListA_1__1__Type" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][1].Field1" id="ListA_1__1__Field1" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][1].Field2" id="ListA_1__1__Field2" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][1].Field3" id="ListA_1__1__Field3" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][1].Field4" id="ListA_1__1__Field4" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][1].Field5" id="ListA_1__1__Field5" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="ListA[1][2].Name" id="ListA_1__2__Name" type="text" value="1 - 2"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][2].Spec" id="ListA_1__2__Spec" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][2].Type" id="ListA_1__2__Type" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][2].Field1" id="ListA_1__2__Field1" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][2].Field2" id="ListA_1__2__Field2" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][2].Field3" id="ListA_1__2__Field3" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][2].Field4" id="ListA_1__2__Field4" type="text"></input>
        <input name="ListA[1][2].Field5" id="ListA_1__2__Field5" type="text"></input>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

---

### Edit 2

I finally managed to make it, rewriting the same code line by line...
So I have no idea why it didn't work before.

Comment: No repro for MVC 4 (with ASPX) & 5 (with Razor) in local machine, also tried with [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WTzP8R) and both lists successfully retrieved on postback. Which list is contained inside first `List` level during postback (with first value of zeroes or ones)?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the ones with `"0 - x"`, and I know it is supposed to work with recent frameworks, this is why I specifically said I was working with a *reaaaally* old framework

Comment: What does the generated html inputs look like?

Comment: @Jonny I edited my question to answer yours

Answer (score 0):

//View

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.MyModel

@{
    Layout = null;
    var model = Model;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index1</title>
</head>
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListA.Count; i++)
    {
    <div>
         @for (int j = 0; j < Model.ListA[i].Count; j++)
         {
        <div>
             @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListA[i][j].Property1)
        </div>
         } 
    </div>
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    }
}
    <p>

        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @rami can you please expolain your answer

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm()){} basically creates a form. the submit button within it will submit the form and convert the fields to json which intern will be consumed by the HTTP post method in controller with model with correct data.

Comment: can you edit your answer, comment your code and explain what you did. This form of answer is not helpful.

Comment: Hello & welcome to StackOverflow. While this surely works as expected with modern frameworks, I fail to see how it differs from my current code (except from the fact that you used Razor when I specifically asked for *.NET Framework 4, MVC 2*, therefore *ASPX*). I'd really like if you could explain what makes you think it answers my question :)